# execution failed for task :app transform resourcewith merge java res for debug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to build an application using apache HTTP libraries. I added jar files to dependencies as show below

[image: Dependencies]

when I run I got the following error:

[image: Error Log]

I added packaging options to Gradle build excluding META-INF/DEPENDENCIES as show in error, but even after that same error shows up.
This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.3.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.5.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: Plase do not use picture for showing error if possible.

Comment: You can copy/paste your gradle error message.

Comment: You can also copy paste your gradle.build file content to show what dependencies you have.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and building again?

Comment: Yeah I tried cleaning and building solution @KamranAhmed

Comment: Try adding this to packagingOptions `exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'`

Comment: Adding exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'  worked...thanks @AshwinMothilal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to packagingOptions `exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'`